# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: better/files/File in spark-sbumit for scala code

Tags: java, scala, apache-spark, sbt, spark-submit

When i export the program into a jar file and execute it i get an java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: better/files/File error.

the code i'm using is below.

Thanks in advance for any assistance

**SBT**

```
name := "testFunctions"

version := "1.0"

scalaVersion := "2.11.8"

libraryDependencies += "com.github.pathikrit" %% "better-files" % "2.17.1"
libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  "org.apache.spark" % "spark-core_2.11" % "2.1.0",
  "org.apache.spark" % "spark-sql_2.11" % "2.1.0",
  "com.github.pathikrit" %% "better-files" % "2.17.1"
)

initialize := {
  val _ = initialize.value
  if (sys.props("java.specification.version") != "1.8")
    sys.error("Java 8 is required for this project.")
}
```

**Scala Code**

```
/**
  * Created by cloudera on 7/23/17.
  */

import better.files.File._
import org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession


object funcJM {


  val forDelete = (root/"/home/cloudera/Documents/fabo")
    .createIfNotExists()

  if (forDelete.exists)
    forDelete.delete()


  def main(args:Array[String]) : Unit = {

    val spark = SparkSession.builder
      .master("local")
      .appName("Get ForEx Data")
      .getOrCreate()



  }

}
```

**Command line executing jar file**

```
spark-submit --class funcJM --master local[*] /home/cloudera/testFunctions/target/scala-2.11/testfunctions_2.11-1.0.jar --driver-class-path /home/cloudera/testFunctions/target/scala-2.11/testfunctions_2.11-1.0.jar
```

**Error**

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:
>   better/files/File     at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native
>   Method)   at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Class.java:2701)
>     at java.lang.Class.privateGetMethodRecursive(Class.java:3048)   at
>   java.lang.Class.getMethod0(Class.java:3018)   at
>   java.lang.Class.getMethod(Class.java:1784)    at
>   org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.org$apache$spark$deploy$SparkSubmit$$runMain(SparkSubmit.scala:722)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.doRunMain$1(SparkSubmit.scala:187)
>     at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.submit(SparkSubmit.scala:212)
>     at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.main(SparkSubmit.scala:126)
>     at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.main(SparkSubmit.scala) Caused
>   by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: better.files.File   at
>   java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)    at
>   java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)     at
>   java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)     ... 10 more

**The Tree structure where the code live looks like below** -
so the class called func lives in the scala directory

```
\main
    \java
    \resources
    \scala
        -funcJM(class)
    \scala-2.11
```

Comment: an simple alternative to the fat jar is described here: https://stackoverflow.com/q/51387919/666886

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are three things you can do:

1. Use something like [sbt assembly](https://github.com/sbt/sbt-assembly) to compile a fat jar. The jar that includes better.files.File will be packaged in testfunctions_2.11-1.0.jar.
2. Copy the jar file that includes the better package into the spark jars directory: ../spark-2.1.0-bin-hadoop2.7/jars
3. Specify the jar file that includes the better package as an argument in your spark-submit call using  `--driver-class-path better-files-akka_2.10.jar`